# Fast-forward merge two branches ignoring specific character pattern

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

Is there a way to merge commits from other branches ignoring specific character pattern like namespace/package with just using fast forward merge?

For example I want to merge few lines in

```
com.company.client1.custom

...public class Bicycle {

// the Bicycle class has
// three fields
public int cadence;
public int gear;
public int speed;
}
```

into another banch where I have this in some file:

```
com.company.client2.custom

...public class Bicycle {

// the Bicycle class has
// three fields
public int cadence;
public int gear;
}
```

I want to merge last code line in snippet, but I don't want to overwrite package the way it is now.

Comment: This cannot possibly work. Are you sure you mean a *fast-forward* merge?

Comment: Well yes. If not FF then it really doesn't matter since I can edit files in merge commit. My coworkers warned me that this probably isn't possible but I think this shouldn't be too complicated and sometimes useful to have in git

Comment: A FF can only happen if one commit is the ancestor of the other commit. You cannot perform merges that way.